# open or close div by animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

i have a form for edit .

in this form i have 2 div .

the first div `editForm` for show form for edit  and second form `infos` for show detail of this form .

i want when the size of page for mobile or tablet the `infos` must be hide and show the button for open it  . its worked and it hide when in the mobile or table size and when click on the button in going hide but i need when the `infos` show or hide with button it using the animation for show or hide .

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rlcd5k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**how can i do this ???**

html :

```
    <div class="container">

    <div id="editForm" class="editForm">
        <form>
            <div class="items">
                <label>name</label>
                <input>
    </div>
                <div class="items">
                    <label>name</label>
                    <input>
    </div>
                    <div class="items">
                        <label>name</label>
                        <input>
    </div>
                        <div class="items">
                            <label>name</label>
                            <input>
    </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="infos" class="infos">
    <ul>
      <li>first</li>
      <li>second</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a (click)="showHideInfo()">open</a>
</div>
```

css:

```
   p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
}
.editForm{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.infos{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
@media (max-width: 768px)
{
  .infos{
    display: none;
    width: 0;
  }
  .editForm{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
#mySidenav a {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #4caf50;
    right: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
    top: 50%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 39px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}
#mySidenav a mat-icon{
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

#mySidenav a:hover {
    right: 0;
}

#about {
    top: 20px;
    background-color: #4caf50;
}
```

and this my code when click on the button for show or hide `infos` :

```
showHideInfo(): void {
    if(this.sidebarShow)
    {

        var editorEdit = document.getElementById('editForm');
        editorEdit.style.visibility='visible';
        editorEdit.style.width='100%';
        var avtionInfo= document.getElementById('infos');
        avtionInfo.style.display='none'
        avtionInfo.style.width='0'
        this.sidebarShow=!this.sidebarShow;
    }else{
        var editorEdit = document.getElementById('editForm');
        editorEdit.style.visibility='hidden';
        editorEdit.style.width='0';
        var avtionInfo= document.getElementById('infos');
        avtionInfo.style.display='block'
        avtionInfo.style.width='100%'
        avtionInfo.style.animation="showInRghit"
        this.sidebarShow=!this.sidebarShow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by giving a transition to the .editForm such as :

```
.editForm{
  transition: width 0.3s ease;
}
```

Please try this and tell if this is the requirement.